# Can we convert this sqlite query from using RANK() OVER( ) to using HAVING clause.?

Tags: sql, sqlite, window-functions

I find this query in some old code, but I am not an experienced SQL / data admin by any mean, Can someone please turn this turn query into some basic one without using the `rank()` function?

```
SELECT memberId, year, AVG(income) avg_income
FROM (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY memberId ORDER BY year DESC) rnk
FROM income
 )
WHERE rnk = 1
GROUP BY memberId, year
```

This query is supposed to do the following:
For each member who has a job, find their `avg_income` in the most recent year they were working.

How can we turn some "fancy" SQL query that uses `rank() over` into a statement that uses the `HAVING` clause instead?

Comment: It's possible. Please share some sample data.

Comment: I don't know if I can share the company data and I think if it is possible, it cloud be done without data since the data could be anything, but the idea /logic is more important here. Thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below query and let me know your feedback:

```
SELECT memberId, year, AVG(income) avg_income
FROM income i
WHERE year =(select max(year) from income im where im.memnberid=i.memberid)
GROUP BY memberId, year
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit ? Thank you for the query. Since now I need to add one more constrain on top of it, like quarter,  without understand the query, how can we find the most recent quarter of the latest year ?

Comment: In pevious query rank() was used to identified all the income from most recent years. I use a sub query to find max(year) for any particular member and used it in where clause.

Comment: I got the idea now. I just add order by memberId, year, quarter.

Comment: That's great to know. Best wishes.

Comment: If you feel that my answer has helped you please mark as accepted by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: Can you please also take a look at this one 

SELECT memberId, year, quarter, AVG(income) avg_income
FROM (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY memberId ORDER BY year DESC, quarter) rnk
  FROM income
)
WHERE rnk = 1
GROUP BY sid, year, quarter

Comment: @Nathan the query seems fine. It will average the income from most recent year's first quarter. If you want the income for last quarter then you can use ORDER BY year DESC, quarter desc instead

Answer (score 0):

For such queries, You can always use `exists/not exists` as follows:

```
SELECT memberId, year, AVG(income) avg_income
FROM income i
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM income ii where i.memberId = ii.memberId and ii.year > i.year)
GROUP BY memberId, year
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but your current solution doesn't work, but can you please take a look at this one 

Can you please also take a look at this one 

SELECT memberId, year, quarter, AVG(income) avg_income
FROM (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY memberId ORDER BY year DESC, quarter) rnk
  FROM income
)
WHERE rnk = 1
GROUP BY sid, year, quarter;

Comment: Do you have quarter also? from where it came into picture?

Comment: yes, This query has the quarter as well. we can assume that it also from the income table.